# Counting simbols in image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm very new at python and I know that is a great language to learn.

My problem is the following:
I've created a script that take screenshots of a site every hour, and I'm trying to create another script to count how much time a bus simbol appears in every image.

One of those screenshot is shown here:
[buses screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bp75.png)

The ideia is to know how much the bus fleet varies throughout the day.

I've already tried something with OpenCV and hashlib, but I couldn't figure out how to make this.

For this project, I'm going to suppose that the buses stoped at "General Osorio" station are not in opperation and don't need to count them.

Any light is welcome.

Thank you all!

Comment: Look into [template matching](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV can do this, as long as you can filter out any bus icons that don't represent active buses (such as in a legend box or perhaps a route list).  You will also need to watch out for decoys that your program interprets as buses.

You may have already recognized that it's a pattern matching plus counting application.

Your project is at a strictly concept level at this point and detailed code isn't going to help you much.  So I'll just provide some general guidance:

1. When I was learning Python, I found www.learnpython.org to be very effective.  Do all of the lessons there first.
2. OpenCV is a bit hit-or-miss with the learning materials right now (2019).  pyimagesearch.com might get you started, but that site is more about procedure than theory.  It's very good and useful as long as you understand that limitation.
3. Get to the point where you can confidently and consistently load and display an image in OpenCV.  Then you'll be ready for the next step of image analysis.
4. GENERALLY, analyzing a grayscale image is simpler than color.  Sometimes the grayscale doesn't contain enough of the information you need and color is simpler.  At any rate, start with grayscale (or filter out a specific color to create a grayscale image).
5. Investigate OpenCV's 'matchTemplate' function.
6. If that isn't suitable, you may be able to use the 'contour' function.
7. A very long shot is the 'blob' function.  You may be able to detect buses from the size (pixel count) of the blob.

-Leland